# Is neoj4 2.2.2 supporting java 8?, error on neo4j/bin/utils script

Tags: java, neo4j

We are testing neo4j 2.2.2 with java 8u45 but we are seeing an error when we start neo4j.

ERROR! Neo4j cannot be started using java version 1.8.0_45.

* Please use Oracle(R) Java(TM) 7 to run Neo4j Server. Download "Java Platform (JDK) 7" from:
  http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html

* Please see http://docs.neo4j.org/ for Neo4j Server installation instructions.

Still the database starts, so the question is: Is this Error message a bug or we should revert the java 8 version to 7.

Error is trigger on /bin/utils script on function checkjvmcompatibility()

Thank you !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According with the neo4j team: it is a bug that will be fixed in an upcoming maintenance release (thank you Viksit Puri).

So release notes are fine and java 8 works well with neo4j version 2.2.2 of Neo4j

Answer (score 1):

It clearly says that you should use Java 7. This is a system requirement, enforced by the library.

But the release notes on the http://docs.neo4j.org/  say:

> Neo4j 2.2.2 is a maintenance release, with critical improvements. Notably, this release: Provides full support for Oracle and OpenJDK **Java 8**.

So either there's a mistake in the documentation, or (more likely) they forgot to update the compatibility check utility. Send them a message on this problem.

http://neo4j.com/contact-us/