# neo4j coudn't start giving error You are using an unsupported version of Java, please use Oracle HotSpot 1 .7

Tags: java, neo4j, installation, java-8, graph-databases

I downloaded java jdk1.8.0_25

but when trying to install neo4j 2.2.2 community zip by this link
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/neo4j/neo4j_zip_environment_setup.htm

it's giving me eror

> C:>Neo4j.bat
>
> ERROR! You are using an unsupported version of Java,
>   please use Oracle HotSpot 1 .7. 2015-06-21 17:31:52.146+0000 INFO 
>   [API] Setting startup timeout to: 120000ms ba sed on 120000 2015-06-21
>   17:31:53.718+0000 INFO  [API] Successfully shutdown Neo4j Server.
>   Can't load log handler "java.util.logging.FileHandler"
>   java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException:
>   data\log\windows-wrapper.0.0.log.lck
>   java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException:
>   data\log\windows-wrapper.0.0.log.lck
>   at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.j
>   ava:79)
>   at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.jav
>   a:97)
>   at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.jav
>   a:102)
>           at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.newFileChannel(WindowsFileSystem
>   Provider.java:115)
>           at java.nio.channels.FileChannel.open(FileChannel.java:287)
>           at java.nio.channels.FileChannel.open(FileChannel.java:335)
>           at java.util.logging.FileHandler.openFiles(FileHandler.java:438)
>           at java.util.logging.FileHandler.(FileHandler.java:255)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstruct
>   orAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingC
>   onstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
>           at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:438)
>           at java.util.logging.LogManager$5.run(LogManager.java:966)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at java.util.logging.LogManager.loadLoggerHandlers(LogManager.java:958)
>           at java.util.logging.LogManager.initializeGlobalHandlers(LogManager.java
>   :1578)
>           at java.util.logging.LogManager.access$1500(LogManager.java:145)
>           at java.util.logging.LogManager$RootLogger.accessCheckedHandlers(LogMana
>   ger.java:1667)
>           at java.util.logging.Logger.getHandlers(Logger.java:1776)
>           at java.util.logging.Logger.log(Logger.java:735)
>           at java.util.logging.Logger.doLog(Logger.java:765)
>           at java.util.logging.Logger.log(Logger.java:788)
>           at java.util.logging.Logger.info(Logger.java:1489)
>           at org.neo4j.wrapper.NeoServiceWrapper.launchAsConsoleApp(NeoServiceWrap
>   per.java:49)
>           at org.neo4j.wrapper.NeoServiceWrapper.main(NeoServiceWrapper.java:35)
>   Jun 21, 2015 11:01:55 PM org.neo4j.wrapper.NeoServiceWrapper
>   launchAsConsoleApp INFO: Params Jun 21, 2015 11:01:55 PM
>   org.neo4j.wrapper.NeoServiceWrapper launchAsConsoleApp INFO:
>   -Dorg.neo4j.server.properties="conf/neo4j-server.properties" Jun 21, 2015 11:01:55 PM org.neo4j.wrapper.NeoServiceWrapper
>   launchAsConsoleApp INFO:
>   -Djava.util.logging.config.file="conf/logging.properties" Jun 21, 2015 11:01:55 PM org.neo4j.wrapper.NeoServiceWrapper launchAsConsoleApp
>   INFO: -Dlog4j.configuration="file:conf/log4j.properties" Jun 21, 2015
>   11:01:55 PM org.neo4j.wrapper.NeoServiceWrapper launchAsConsoleApp
>   INFO: "-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC" Jun 21, 2015 11:01:55 PM
>   org.neo4j.wrapper.NeoServiceWrapper launchAsConsoleApp INFO:
>   "-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled" Jun 21, 2015 11:01:55 PM
>   org.neo4j.wrapper.NeoServiceWrapper launchAsConsoleApp INFO:
>   "-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow" Jun 21, 2015 11:01:55 PM
>   org.neo4j.wrapper.NeoServiceWrapper launchAsConsoleApp INFO:
>   "-XX:hashCode=5" Jun 21, 2015 11:01:55 PM
>   org.neo4j.wrapper.NeoServiceWrapper launchAsConsoleApp INFO:
>   -Dneo4j.ext.udc.source="zip" Jun 21, 2015 11:01:55 PM org.neo4j.wrapper.NeoServiceWrapper launchAsConsoleApp INFO:
>   Classpath: "-classpath"
>   "C:\PROGRA~1\NEO4J-~1.2\bin..\lib\concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru-1.4.jar;C:\PROGRA~1\NEO4J-~1.2\bin..\lib\lucene-core-3.6.2.jar;C:\PROGRA~1\NEO4J-~1.2\bin..\lib\neo4j-consistency-check-2.2.2.jar;C:\PROGRA~1\NEO4J-~1.2\bin..\lib\neo4j-csv-2.2.2.jar;C:\PROGRA~1\NEO4J-~1.2\bin..\lib\neo4j-cypher-2.2.2.jar;C:\PROGRA~1\NEO4J-~1.2\bin..\lib\neo4j-cypher-compiler-1.9-2.0.4.jar;C:\PROGRA~1\NEO4J-~1.2\bin..\lib\neo4j-cypher-compiler-2.0-2.0.4.jar;C:\PROGRA~1\NEO4J-~1.2\bin..\lib\neo4j-cypher-compiler-2.1-2.1.8.jar;C:\PROGRA~1\NEO4J-~1.2\bin..\lib\neo4j-cypher-compiler-2.2-2.2.2.jar;C:\PROGRA~1\NEO4J-~1.2\bin..\lib\neo4j-graph-algo-2.2.2.jar;C:\PROGRA~1\NEO4J-~1.2\bin..\lib\neo4j-graph-matching-2.2.2.jar;C:\PROGRA~1\NEO4J-~1.2\bin..\lib\neo4j-import-tool-2.2.2.jar;C:\PROGRA~1\NEO4J-~1.2\bin..\lib\neo4j-io-2.2.2.jar;C:\PROGRA~1\NEO4J-~1.2\bin..\lib\neo4j-jmx-2.2.2.jar;C:\PROGRA~1\NEO4J-~1.2\bin..\lib\neo4j-kernel-2.2.2.jar;C:\PROGRA~1\NEO4J-~1.2\bin..\lib\neo4j-lucene-index-2.2.2.jar;C:\PROGRA~1\NEO4J-~1.2\bin..\lib\neo4j-primitive-collections-2.2.2.jar;C:\PROGRA~1\NEO4J-~1.2\bin..\lib\neo4j-shell-2.2.2.jar;C:\PROGRA~1\NEO4J-~1.2\bin..\lib\neo4j-udc-2.2.2.jar;C:\PROGRA~1\NEO4J-~1.2\bin..\lib\neo4j-unsafe-2.2.2.jar;C:\PROGRA~1\NEO4J-~1.2\bin..\lib\opencsv-2.3.jar;C:\PROGRA~1\NEO4J-~1.2\bin..\lib\org.apache.servicemix.bundles.jline-0.9.94_1.jar;C:\PROGRA~1\NEO4J-~1.2\bin..\lib\parboiled-core-1.1.7.jar;C:\PROGRA~1\NEO4J-~1.2\bin..\lib\parboiled-scala_2.10-1.1.7.jar;C:\PROGRA~1\NEO4J-~1.2\bin..\lib\scala-library-2.10.5.jar;C:\PROGRA~1\NEO4J-~1.2\bin..\lib\server-api-2.2.2.jar;C:\PROGRA~1\NEO4J-~1.2\bin..\system\lib\bcprov-jdk16-140.jar;C:\PROGRA~1\NEO4J-~1.2\bin..\system\lib\commons-beanutils-1.8.3.jar;C:\PROGRA~1\NEO4J-~1.2\bin..\system\lib\commons-compiler-2.6.1.jar;C:\PROGRA~1\NEO4J-~1.2\bin..\system\lib\commons-configuration-1.10.jar;C:\PROGRA~1\NEO4J-~1.2\bin..\system\lib\commons-digester-2.1.jar;C:\PROGRA~1\NEO4J-~1.2\bin..\system\lib\commons-io-2.4.jar;C:\PROGRA~1\NEO4J-~1.2\bin..\system\lib\commons-lang-2.6.jar;C:\PROGRA~1\NEO4J-~1.2\bin..\system\lib\commons-logging-1.1.1.jar;C:\PROGRA~1\NEO4J-~1.2\bin..\system\lib\jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar;C:\PROGRA~1\NEO4J-~1.2\bin..\system\lib\jackson-jaxrs-1.9.13.jar;C:\PROGRA~1\NEO4J-~1.2\bin..\system\lib\jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar;C:\PROGRA~1\NEO4J-~1.2\bin..\system\lib\janino-2.6.1.jar;C:\PROGRA~1\NEO4J-~1.2\bin..\system\lib\javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar;C:\PROGRA~1\NEO4J-~1.2\bin..\system\lib\jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.7.jar;C:\PROGRA~1\NEO4J-~1.2\bin..\system\lib\jersey-core-1.18.1.jar;C:\PROGRA~1\NEO4J-~1.2\bin..\system\lib\jersey-multipart-1.18.1.jar;C:\PROGRA~1\NEO4J-~1.2\bin..\system\lib\jersey-server-1.18.1.jar;C:\PROGRA~1\NEO4J-~1.2\bin..\system\lib\jersey-servlet-1.18.1.jar;C:\PROGRA~1\NEO4J-~1.2\bin..\system\lib\jetty-http-9.2.4.v20141103.jar;C:\PROGRA~1\NEO4J-~1.2\bin..\system\lib\jetty-io-9.2.4.v20141103.jar;C:\PROGRA~1\NEO4J-~1.2\bin..\system\lib\jetty-security-9.2.4.v20141103.jar;C:\PROGRA~1\NEO4J-~1.2\bin..\system\lib\jetty-server-9.2.4.v20141103.jar;C:\PROGRA~1\NEO4J-~1.2\bin..\system\lib\jetty-servlet-9.2.4.v20141103.jar;C:\PROGRA~1\NEO4J-~1.2\bin..\system\lib\jetty-util-9.2.4.v20141103.jar;C:\PROGRA~1\NEO4J-~1.2\bin..\system\lib\jetty-webapp-9.2.4.v20141103.jar;C:\PROGRA~1\NEO 4J-~1.2\bin..\system\lib\jetty-xml-9.2.4.v20141103.jar;C:\PROGRA~1\NEO4J-~1.2\bin..\system\lib\jsr311-api-1.1.2.r612.jar;C:\PROGRA~1\NEO4J-~1.2\bin..\system\lib\logback-access-1.1.2.jar;C:\PROGRA~1\NEO4J-~1.2\bin..\system\lib\logback-classic-1.1.2.jar;C:\PROGRA~1\NEO4J-~1.2\bin..\system\lib\logback-core-1.1.2.jar; C:\PROGRA~1\NEO4J-~1.2\bin..\system\lib\mimepull-1.9.3.jar;C:\PROGRA~1\NEO4J-~1.2\bin..\system\lib\neo4j-browser-2.2.2.jar;C:\PROGRA~1\NEO4J-~1.2\bin..\system\lib\neo4j-server-2.2.2-static-web.jar;C:\PROGRA~1\NEO4J-~1.2\bin..\system\lib\neo4j-server-2.2.2.jar;C:\PROGRA~1\NEO4J-~1.2\bin..\system\lib\rhino-1.7R4.jar;C:\PROGRA~1\NEO4J-~1.2\bin..\system\lib\rrd4j-2.2.jar;C:\PROGRA~1\NEO4J-~1.2\bin..\system\lib\scala-reflect-2.10.5.jar;C:\PROGRA~1\NEO4J-~1.2\bin..\system\lib\slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar;C:\PROGRA~1\NEO4J-~1.2\bin...\conf;" Jun 21,
>   2015 11:01:55 PM org.neo4j.wrapper.NeoServiceWrapper
>   launchAsConsoleApp INFO: Main class: org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper Jun
>   21, 2015 11:01:55 PM org.neo4j.wrapper.NeoServiceWrapper
>   launchAsConsoleApp INFO: Args:
>
> C:>

does its only support java 1.7??
but i see neo4j documentation its says that it supports 1.8 also

Comment: Why don't you try downloading from the official neo4j link? http://neo4j.com/download/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neo4j 2.2.2 does support Java 8, the compatibility error message is incorrect (see [Is neoj4 2.2.2 supporting java 8?, error on neo4j/bin/utils script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30633222/is-neoj4-2-2-2-supporting-java-8-error-on-neo4j-bin-utils-script))

As for the log file, it should log to `NEO4J_HOME/data/log`, perhaps you have no permissions?

Comment: @Launne yes that was a problem of permission